# Task scheduling algorithm

Tags: algorithm, scheduled-tasks, dynamic-programming

How do I go about the following problem? I have a sense to use DP

Given an array of the complexity of task, Note that the complexity is also the order of the task they need to be executed. The constraint is to have at least one task scheduled every day. The complexity of that day is the highest task complexity of that day. What is the overall minimum complexity that can be achieved with optimal planning?

For example, let's say there are `n = 5` tasks, where:

```py
complexity = [1, 5, 3, 2, 4]
```

and the length of the test is `days = 2`. The best option is to execute the first task on the first day and the rest on the second day. The complexity of the first day would be 1, since that's the only task, and the complexity of the second day would be 5, because that's the complexity level of the most complex task that day. Therefore, the answer is `1 + 5 = 6`.

```sh
Example 1:
5 -> complexity[] size n = 5
30
10
40
20
50
2 -> Days =2
```

Output:

```sh
80
```

Comment: I couldn't get, how choices `1 + 5 = 6` is the optimal in your example, `Note that the complexity is also the order of the task they need to be executed`, could you clarify which order ?, if you mean the array in order, then I guess the problem formulation would be wrong.

Comment: @4.Pi.n not the order of indexes. It means I need to do task with complexity 1 first, then task with complexity 2, then 3... in the first example.

Comment: In your example, why you choose `1 + 5 = 6`, to be the optimal, why not choose `1 + 2 = 3`, What's the constraint implies that choice?.

Comment: because of this description: "the complexity of that day is the highest task complexity of that day". so the first day we complete 1, the second day we complete, 2,3,4,5, so the total complexity is 1+5=6

Comment: sorry, I think you're right about the order. I think it indeed means the task should be planned according to the indexes. Otherwise the answer to example 1 should be 60 instead of 80.@4.Pi.n

Answer (score 0):

I think this is O(n<sup>2</sup>), so not super optimal, but it works. It's written in Go.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func optimize(tasks []int, days int) int {
    // edge case 1: empty c or days <= 0
    // (this is really for data input validation)
    if len(tasks) == 0 || days <= 0 {
        return 0
    }
    // edge case 2: single day - return max
    if days == 1 {
        max := tasks[0]
        for _, v := range tasks[1:] {
            if v > max {
                max = v
            }
        }
        return max
    }
    // edge case 3: tasks = days
    if days == len(tasks) {
        total := 0
        for _, v := range tasks {
            total += v
        }
        return total
    }
    // all other cases:
    possibilities := []int{}
    i := 0
    max := tasks[0]
    for {
        tasksLeft := len(tasks[i+1:])
        daysLeft := days - 1
        if tasksLeft < daysLeft {
            break
        }
        if tasks[i] > max {
            max = tasks[i]
        }
        possibility := max + optimize(tasks[i+1:], days-1)
        possibilities = append(possibilities, possibility)
        i++
    }
    // minimize
    min := possibilities[0]
    for _, p := range possibilities[1:] {
        if p < min {
            min = p
        }
    }
    return min
}

func main() {
    tasks := []int{1, 5, 3, 2, 4}
    days := 2
    fmt.Println(optimize(tasks, days))
}
```